# Insert elements after certain results in each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

Please take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ56N/2/)

Is there any way to insert an element `<h3>text</h3>`after `link - google.com` and `<h3>sss</h3>` after `color - Black` inside the second loop?

I want the outcome to be like this:

```
title - A

link - google.com

<h3>text</h3>

image - image.com

price - $1295.00

brand - ABC

color - Black

<h3>sss</h3>

material - Rubber
```

Here's the json file and the code:

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "title": "A",
    "link": "google.com",
    "image": "image.com",
    "price": "$1295.00",
    "brand": "ABC",
    "color": "Black",
    "material": "Rubber"
  }
]
```

JS:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%20%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2FaZgYDB%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=",
        success: function (data) {
            var item_html="";
            $(data.query.results.json).each(function(key, value) {
              $.each(value,function(key, value){                             
               item_html += '<h3>'+key+' - '+value+'</h3>';                        
              });
            });            

           $('#area').append(item_html);

        }
    });
```

Comment: relatively simple to do using a conditional `if` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Answer (score 1):

You can check the key value and append something as follows

```
$.each(value, function (key, value) {   
      item_html += '<h3>' + key + ' - ' + value + '</h3>';
      if(key=='link')
         item_html += '<h3>something</h3>';
      if(key=='color')
         item_html += '<h3>something else</h3>';

  });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ56N/5/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just looking for a simple `if` statement:

```
if(value == "google.com"){
    item_html += '<h3>Text</h3>';
}
if(value == "Black" && key == "color"){
    item_html += '<h3>SecondText</h3>';   
}
```

You could also check for both the key and the value (second if statement) if you want to be sure.

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ56N/3/)